# Используя SMSegmentView не могу реализовать switch в numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile

Использую фрэйм SMSegmentView, не могу реализовать switch в numberOfRowsInSection и в cellForRowAtIndexPath... выдает ошибку Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type '(Int) -> ()'. Не могу понять ошибку

```
import UIKit

class DailyStandingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SMSegmentViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var standingTableView: UITableView!

let standingExersiseName = ["БЕГ", "ПРЫЖКИ", "ПРИСЕДАНИЯ", "ОТЖИМАНИЯ", "ТОЛЧЕК"]
let standingExersiseImage = ["bb", "bt", "ca", "co", "de"]

let sittingExersiseName = ["ПРИСЕД", "СКАЧКИ", "ПРИСЕДАНИЯ", "ОТЖИМАНИЯ", "ТОЛЧЕК"]
let sittingExersiseImage = ["bb", "bt", "ca", "co", "de"]

var segmentControler: SMSegmentView!
var alphaSegmentView: SMBasicSegmentView!
var seletionBar: UIView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //СОЗДАЕМ СЕГМЕНТ
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(-5.0 , 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width + 10, 40.0)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let segmentFrame = CGRect(x: -5.0 , y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width + 10, height: 40.0)

    self.segmentControler = SMSegmentView(frame: segmentFrame, separatorColour: UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), separatorWidth: 0.0, segmentProperties: [keySegmentTitleFont: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0), keySegmentOnSelectionColour: UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), keySegmentOffSelectionColour: UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])

    self.segmentControler.delegate = self
    self.segmentControler.addSegmentWithTitle("STANDING", onSelectionImage: nil, offSelectionImage: nil)
    self.segmentControler.addSegmentWithTitle("SITTING", onSelectionImage: nil, offSelectionImage: nil)
    self.segmentControler.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    self.seletionBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 33.5, width: self.segmentControler.frame.size.width/CGFloat(self.segmentControler.numberOfSegments), height: 6.0)
    self.seletionBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.segmentControler.selectSegmentAtIndex(0)

    self.view.addSubview(self.segmentControler)
}
func segmentView(segmentView: SMBasicSegmentView, didSelectSegmentAtIndex index: Int) {

     let placeSelectionBar = { () -> () in
        var barFrame = self.seletionBar.frame
        barFrame.origin.x = barFrame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        self.seletionBar.frame = barFrame
    }
    if self.seletionBar.superview == nil {
        self.segmentControler.addSubview(self.seletionBar)
        placeSelectionBar()
    }
    else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            placeSelectionBar()
        })
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var returnValue = 0

    switch (segmentControler.selectSegmentAtIndex) {
    case 0: //Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type '(Int) -> ()'
        returnValue = standingExersiseName.count
        break
    case 1: //Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type '(Int) -> ()'
        returnValue = sittingExersiseName.count
        break

    default:
        break
    }
     return returnValue
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    switch (segmentControler.selectSegmentAtIndex) {
    case 0: //Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type '(Int) -> ()'
        myCell.textLabel?.text = standingExersiseName[indexPath.row]
        myCell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:standingExersiseImage[indexPath.row])
        break
    case 1: //Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type '(Int) -> ()'
        myCell.textLabel?.text = sittingExersiseName[indexPath.row]
        myCell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:sittingExersiseImage[indexPath.row])
        break

    default:
        break
    }

    return myCell
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectSegmentAtIndex` это сеттер - он принимает индекс и возвращает void. Вы не можете его использовать как условие для switch.

Мне кажется `indexOfSelectedSegment` это то, что вам надо.

Comment: Ошибка ушла, но switch не работает, при запуске в симуляторе смены таблицы по нажатию на сегмент не происходит

Comment: вам надо по нажатию делать `standingTableView.reloadData()`